# Como Validando o formulário sem dar Refresh na página e perder os campos já preenchidos?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário e estou usando javascript para validar se os campos do formulário foram preenchidos ou não, só então depois de preenchido o usuário pode prosseguir, porém, quando é clicado no input "submit" a página inteira é atualizada, excluindo os dados dos campos já preenchidos. Há um jeito de manter as informações dos campos já preenchidos quando clico em enviar ( sem que a página de Refresh e o usuário perca os campos que já foram preenchidos) ?

segue código:

```
        <fieldset> <!--INFORMAÇÕES PESSOAIS-->
            <legend>Informações pessoais:</legend>
            <div>
                <!--legenda-->
                <label>Nome</label>
                <br>
                <!--Entrada de valor-->
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Insira o seu nome" >
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Insira o seu E-mail">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Idade</label>
                <br>
                <input type="number" min="10" name="idade" id="idade" placeholder="insira a sua idade">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Qual opção descreve melhor sua função atual?</label><br>
                <select name="ocupacao" id="funcao">
                    <option disabled selected value>Selecione sua função atual</option>
                    <option>Estudante</option>
                    <option>Trabalho em tempo integral</option>
                    <option>Aprendiz em tempo integral</option>
                    <option>Prefiro não dizer</option>
                    <option>Outra..</option>
                </select>
            </div>
           
        </fieldset>


----------------------------------------------------javascript \/----------------------------

function validarFormPesquisa () {
    var nome = formPesquisa.nome.value;
    var email = formPesquisa.email.value;
    var idade = formPesquisa.idade.value;
    var ocupacao = formPesquisa.ocupacao.value;

    if(nome == ""){
        alert("Campo nome é obrigatorio");
        formPesquisa.nome.focus();
        return false;
    };

    if(email == ""){
        alert("Campo email é obrigatorio");
        formPesquisa.email.focus();
        return false;
    };
    if(idade == ""){
        alert("Campo idade é obrigatorio");
        formPesquisa.idade.focus();
        return false;
    };
    if(ocupacao == ""){
        alert("Campo ocupacao é obrigatorio");
        formPesquisa.ocupacao.focus();
        return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acredito que vc possa fazer de duas formas.

1. Realize o envio via ajax, evite o `submit` padrão do botão e dessa forma adicione uma função para o evento `click`:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){<br>
e.preventDefault();

    // aqui vai todo teu código

});
```

2. Realize a verificação no evento `change` ou `blur` para cada input.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for(i=0; i < inputs.lengh; i++){
   inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
       
      // Aqui tu realiza as validações

   });
}
```